# running curl with sudo results in a status code 301 (Moved Permanently)

Tags: sudo, curl, http

i have a test server running on port 3062, i want to send it HTTP POST data using curl

when i run the following command :

```
curl -d '{"k1":"v1","k2","v2"}' -X POST http://localhost:3062
```

it works fine i get the response

but when i run the following:

```
sudo curl -d '{"k1":"v1","k2","v2"}' -X POST http://localhost:3062
```

i get: 
301 and a redirect page

I cannot remove the sudo as the curl command is part of a much larger script that requires it.

Comment: I don't suppose you're using a proxy in an environment variable, and the server at 3062 requires users to come from the proxy? `sudo` could be dropping the variable.

Comment: @JeffSchaller i am using proxy env' variable, how do i run sudo so it does not drop env variables ?

Comment: I'm honestly very surprised, but my kneejerk reaction would be to modify the `curl` call to explicitly use a proxy with  the `--proxy` command-line option.

Comment: @JeffSchaller sadly i cannot modify the script, thanks for the direction though, ill see how i can configure sudo to recognize same env'

Comment: I will suggest https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13246/117549 as the (duplicate) answer to the problem. (translate HOME to your proxy variable)

Answer (score 0):

As to [Jeff Schaller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) response i checked online, 
indeed sudo cleans env' variables

in order to preserve env' variables need to run `sudo -E`

once i ran with this, it worked great